# Feynman Rules from Generating Functional

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, partition-function

For the following Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}= \overline \psi \left(i \gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu} - m \right)\psi -\frac{1}{2}\left(F_{\mu\nu}\right)^2,$$

I'm trying to find the Feynman rules. I know that the second derivative of the generating functional gives me the propagators and the third derivative gives me the vertices of the theory, so I started by defining the generating functional for this theory:

$$ Z[\eta,\overline \eta, J_{\mu}] := \int \mathcal D\overline \psi \mathcal D \psi \mathcal D A_{\mu} \exp{\left(i\left(\mathcal L + J^{\mu} A_{\mu} + i\eta\overline\psi + i\overline \eta\psi \right) \right)} \,  \; \; (1)$$

However, I don't know how to "complete the square" and shift the fields to get the propagators.

For example, considering only the Dirac fields

$$ Z[\eta,\overline \eta] := \int \mathcal D\overline \psi \mathcal D \psi \ \exp{\left(i \overline \psi \left(i\gamma^\mu{\partial_\mu} - m_0\right) \psi + i\eta\overline\psi + i\overline \eta\psi\right)} \,. $$

Integrating by parts the first factor and shifting the fields, we get:

$$ Z[\eta,\overline \eta] := \int \mathcal D\overline \psi \mathcal D \psi \ \exp{\left(-\int d^4x d^4y \; \overline\eta(x) S_{F}(x-y) \eta(y) \right)} \,. $$

Now we can calculate the 2-point function:

$$\langle \psi(x_1) \overline \psi(x_2) \rangle = \frac{1}{Z_{0}} \left(-i\frac{\delta}{\delta \overline \eta} \right)\left(i\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta} \right)Z[J]|_{J = 0} = S_F(x_1-x_2)$$

and this is the propagator for this theory.

After using the Fadeev-Popov method to eliminate equal configurations of the electromagnetic field and using the same procedure for $\mathcal{L}= -\frac{1}{2}\left(F_{\mu\nu}\right)^2,$ one arrives to the photon propagator.

**Questions:**

Can I separate the Lagrangian into $\mathcal L = \mathcal L_{Dirac} + \mathcal L_{EM}$ and use the procedure above to get the vertex and propagators for the global Lagrangian?

Is there way of "completing the square" and shifting the fields in equation (1)?

Is there another way of using the generating functional to get the vertex and propagators of a theory?

Comment: What do you mean “glabal Lagrangean”?  Maybe you mean "using any gauge-fixing condition", don’t you?